# finding the frequency of a motif-matching peptide

Tags: phylogenetics, proteins, python, motifs, homework

*This question has also been asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9545742/)*

I want to find the frequency of each motif-matching peptide.
The sequences are:

```
> Sequence_1
MPPRRSIVEVKVLDVQKRRVPNKHYVYIIRVTWSSGATEAIYRRYSKFFDLQMQMLDKFP
MEGGQKDPKQRIIPFLPGKILFRRSHIRDVAVKRLIPIDEYCKALIQLPPYISQCDEVLQ
FFETRPEDLNPPKEEHIGKKKSGNDPTSVDPMVLEQYVVVADYQKQESSEISLSVGQVVD
IIEKNESGWWFVSTAEEQGWVPATCLEGQDGVQDEFSLQPEEEEKYTVIYPYTARDQDEM
NLERGAVVEVVQKNLEGWWKIRYQGKEGWAPASYLKKNSGEPLPPKLGPSSPAHSGALDL
DGVSRHQNAMGREKELLNNQRDGRFEGRLVPDGDVKQRSPKMRQRPPPRRDMTIPRGLNL

>Sequence_2
MAEVRKFTKRLSKPGTAAELRQSVSEAVRGSVVLEKAKLVEPLDYENVITQRKTQIYSDP
LRDLLMFPMEDISISVIGRQRRTVQSTVPEDAEKRAQSLFVKECIKTYSTDWHVVNYKYE
DFSGDFRMLPCKSLRPEKIPNHVFEIDEDCEKDEDSSSLCSQKGGVIKQGWLHKANVNST
ITVTMKVFKRRYFYLTQLPDGSYILNSYKDEKNSKESKGCIYLDACIDVVQCPKMRRHAF
ELKMLDKYSHYLAAETEQEMEEWLIMLKKIIQINTDSLVQEKKDTVEAIQEEETSSQGKA
ENIMASLERSMHPELMKYGRETEQLNKLSRGDGRQNLFSFDSEVQRLDFSGIEPDVKPFE
EKCNKRFMVNCHDLTFNILGHIGDNAKGPPTNVEPFFINLALFDVKNNCKISADFHVDLN
PPSVREMLWGTSTQLSNDGNAKGFSPESLIHGIAESQLCYIKQGIFSVTNPHPEIFLVVR

>Sequence_3
GDDSEWLKLPVDQKCEHKLWKARLSGYEEALKIFQKIKDEKSPEWSKYLGLIKKFVTDS
NAVVQLKGLEAALVYVENAHVAGKTTGEVVSGVVSKVFNQPKAKAKELGIEICLMYVEIE
KGESVQEELLKGLDNKNPKIIVACIETLRKALSEFGSKIISLKPIIKVLPKLFESRDKAV
RDEAKLFAIEIYRWNRDAVKHTLQNINSVQLKELEEEWVKLPTGAPKPSRFLRSQQELEA
KLEQQQSAGGDAEGGGDDGDEVPQVDAYELLDAVEILSKLPKDFYDKIEAKKWQERKEAL
EAVEVLVKNPKLEAGDYADLVKALKKVVGKDTNVMLVALAAKCLTGLAVGLRKKFGQYAG
HVVPTILEKFKEKKPQVVQALQEAIDAIFLTTTLQNISEDVLAVMDNKNPTIKQQTSLFI
ARSFRHCTSSTLPKSLLKPFCAALLKHINDSAPEVRDAAFEALGTALKVVGEKSVNPFLA

> Sequence_4
MPPRRSIVEVKVLDVQKRRVPNKHYVYIIRVTWSSGATEAIYRRYSKFFDLQMQMLDKFP
MEGGQKDPKQRIIPFLPGKILFRRSHIRDVAVKRLIPIDEYCKALIQLPPYISQCDEVLQ
FFETRPEDLNPPKEEHIGKKKSGNDPTSVDPMVLEQYVVVADYQKQESSEISLSVGQVVD
IIEKNESGWWFVSTAEEQGWVPATCLEGQDGVQDEFSLQPEEEEKYTVIYPYTARDQDEM
NLERGAVVEVVQKNLEGWWKIRYQGKEGWAPASYLKKNSGEPLPPKLGPSSPAHSGALDL
DGVSRHQNAMGREKELLNNQRDGRFEGRLVPDGDVKQRSPKMRQRPPPRRDMTIPRGLNL 


>Sequence_5
GDDSEWLKLPVDQKCEHKLWKARLSGYEEALKIFQKIKDEKSPEWSKYLGLIKKFVTDS
NAVVQLKGLEAALVYVENAHVAGKTTGEVVSGVVSKVFNQPKAKAKELGIEICLMYVEIE
KGESVQEELLKGLDNKNPKIIVACIETLRKALSEFGSKIISLKPIIKVLPKLFESRDKAV
RDEAKLFAIEIYRWNRDAVKHTLQNINSVQLKELEEEWVKLPTGAPKPSRFLRSQQELEA
KLEQQQSAGGDAEGGGDDGDEVPQVDAYELLDAVEILSKLPKDFYDKIEAKKWQERKEAL
EAVEVLVKNPKLEAGDYADLVKALKKVVGKDTNVMLVALAAKCLTGLAVGLRKKFGQYAG
HVVPTILEKFKEKKPQVVQALQEAIDAIFLTTTLQNISEDVLAVMDNKNPTIKQQTSLFI
ARSFRHCTSSTLPKSLLKPFCAALLKHINDSAPEVRDAAFEALGTALKVVGEKSVNPFLA
```

The fasta file actually has more sequences, I just chose the top 5, to put on here.

The code used is below:

```
import Bio
import regex

from Bio import SeqIO
input_file = 'Sequences.fasta'
fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open(input_file),'fasta')
for fasta in fasta_sequences:
     name, sequence = fasta.id, str(fasta.seq)
     matches=regex.finditer(r"(P[A-Z]{2}P..)",sequence)
     for m in matches:
        print(name, m.start(), m.end(), m.group())
```

This is giving me my desired output, which is below:

```
Sequence1 73 79 PFLPGK
Sequence1 281 287 PLPPKL
Sequence1 288 294 PSSPAH
Sequence4 73 79 PFLPGK
Sequence4 281 287 PLPPKL
Sequence4 288 294 PSSPAH
```

Now I want to:

1. Calculate the number of sequences in that file. I know in linux environment I would have to use `grep -c ">" Sequences.fasta` to get the total number of sequences in the fasta file, but how do I do it in python?.
2. Once I know how many sequences are in file in total, I want to count how many of those sequences have the motif-matching peptides above.
   For example how many sequences have PFLPGK at positions 73 79? In the example above PFLPGK its in sequence 1 & 4, so the **frequency** is 2, meaning that two sequences have PFLPGK. How do I find that frequency for each of the peptides using python.

Many thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Hi @thole the historic protocol on the site was to ask an OP what code has already been written to address in this instance Q 1 and 2. I personally think there should be a grace period. However, please avoid asking the site to write your code base from scratch for future reference.

Comment: Yes, pelase don't treat this site as a free script writing service. We are happy to _help_ you with your work, but we won't just write it for you like this.

Comment: Just to add, this just for Q2. Q1 is a fair question by itself any time and I like the solution.

Comment: @M__ thank you, I was able to finally figure out how to work on Q1 without using Biopython. As for Q2 I am still working on it. Do you by any chance have any suggestions on books or free sites that I can use to continue learn python? Once again thank you for your suggestions

Comment: @thole post updated as requested, the information sort is below the `------`. There was a bug in my implementation of `Q1` it now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part is easy,

```
from Bio import SeqIO
seqs = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse("myfile.fa", "fasta"))
print (len(seqs))
```

The second part is solvable Python's amazing slicing, this is the concept ....

```
from Bio import SeqIO
loci = {'PFLPGK':[1,10], 'PFLPGK':[50:60] }   
fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open(input_file),'fasta')
mydict = {}
for key, values in loci.items():
    myrange = '-'.join(values)
    mydict = {key:myrange} # you need to initiate the dictionary without defaultdict
    for record in fasta_sequences:
        if record.seq[values[0]-1:values[1]-1] == key:
             mydict[key][myrange].append(record.id)
```

To print it:

```
key, value in mydict.items():
    print("No. of" + key + '=' + len(mydict[key][value]))
```

**Note 1**, the second answer is concept only.

**Note 2** there can be an issue between the `list` location and the sequence location ... that is **super** important otherwise it will not work. I've added `-1` from both locations of the amino acid and the location on the `list`, *but this needs checking*. This is because `list`s start at `0` whilst amino acids start at `1`

---

**Update** *Advice on Python* requested by OP

1. Answer to Q1 has been debugged, tested and works.
2. Use Q2 as the basis ... just debug it (see point 4.), it will be a bit fiddly because moving from `lists` to aa strings.
3. Use an IDE, I use Spyder: don't get too caught up in "the best IDE" they just make life easier.
4. Book: Mark Lutz "Learning Python 5th Edition" by O'Reilly section on `lists` (slicing) and `dictionaries`  *****.
5. Online resources `GeekforGeeks` on [`lists`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lists/) (slicing) and [`dictionaries`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/).
6. [BioPython docs on SeqIO](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) search for `record.id` and `record.seq` ... you need to understand the SeqIO object.

***** This is physically a huge book so an electronic version is strongly preferred just for logistics. This goes beyond the full modern implementation of `OOP` in bioinformatics (which is not very modern in truth and can become unreadable).